# Replace with jquery while fading in and out

Tags: jquery, replace, jquery-animate, fade

I am trying to fade in the second button when the first button is faded out. Please reply if you have any suggestions.

```js
 $
 $(document).on('click',"#firstbutton",function(){
  $('#firstbutton').fadeOut("5000", function(){
  var div = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
   $('#firstbutton').replaceWith(div).fadeIn("5000", function(){
 });
 });
  });
  
  
  $(document).on('click',"#secondbutton",function(){
  $('#secondbutton').fadeOut("5000", function(){
  var div = $("<button id='firstbutton'>First button</button>");
   $('#secondbutton').replaceWith(div).fadeIn("5000", function(){
 });;
 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="firstbutton">First button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery only once (you have included it three times):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Format your script properly:

```
$(document).on('click', "#firstbutton", function () {
    $('#firstbutton').fadeOut("5000", function () {
        var div = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
            $('#firstbutton').replaceWith(div).fadeIn("5000", function () {
        });
    });
});


$(document).on('click', "#secondbutton", function () {
    $('#secondbutton').fadeOut("5000", function () {
        var div = $("<button id='firstbutton'>First button</button>");
            $('#secondbutton').replaceWith(div).fadeIn("5000", function () {
        });
    });
});
```

And make sure you run the script *after* jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: It makes no sense and you could not answer to it either.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to me, and it works when I run it. I'm just trying to give you some of my time to help you :-) and it is almost exactly what you posted as an answer one minute after I posted this.

Answer (score -1):

I found the following solution:

```js
 $(document).on('click',"#firstbutton",function(){
 $('#firstbutton').fadeOut("5000", function(){
  var div = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>").fadeIn(3000);  
  $('#firstbutton').replaceWith(div);
  });
  });
  
  $(document).on('click',"#secondbutton",function(){
 $('#secondbutton').fadeOut("5000", function(){
  var div = $("<button id='firstbutton'>First button</button>").fadeIn(3000);  
  $('#secondbutton').replaceWith(div);
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <button id="firstbutton">First button</button>
```